# Sum array values with specified index in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have arrays like this:

```
['[camera_positive,3]', '[lens_positive,1]', '[camera_positive,2]', '[lens_positive,1]', '[lens_positive,1]', '[camera_positive,1]']
```

How to sum all value on index [1] with same string on index [0]?
Example:

```
camera_positive = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6
lens_positive = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

Comment: do you know the strings in advance?

Comment: that is a list of strings, not a list of lists? Is that correct?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you familiar with list comprehensions?  Have you used the `Collections` package at all?  These are useful tools for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set` in order to extract the unique keys and then use list comprehension to compute the sum for each key:

```
data = [['camera_positive', 3], 
        ['lens_positive', 1], 
        ['camera_positive', 2], 
        ['lens_positive', 1], 
        ['lens_positive', 1], 
        ['camera_positive', 1]]

keys = set(key for key, value in data)

for key1 in keys:
    total = sum(value for key2, value in data if key1 == key2)
    print("key='{}', sum={}".format(key1, total))
```

this gives:

```
key='camera_positive', sum=6
key='lens_positive', sum=3
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, i've delete my recent comment in this section. I've tried your suggestion and it works like a charm! So simple, no need library and etc. I've accepted your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a list of list, not a list of strings as shown in the question. Otherwise you'll have to do some parsing. That said, I would solve this problem by creating a dictionary, and then iterating over the values and adding them to the dictionary as you go.

The default dict allows this program to work without getting a key error, as it'll assume `0` if the key does not exist yet. You can read up on `defaultdict` here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

lmk if that helps!

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
>>> lst=[['a',1], ['b', 2], ['a',4]]
>>> for k, v in lst:
...   d[k] += v
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 5, 'b': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the entries by their first index using [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with `lambda x: x[0]` or `operator.itemgetter(0)` as key.

This is maybe a bit less code than what Nick Brady showed. However you would need to sort the list first (for the same key), so it might be slower than his approach.